# How can I create or delete tabs in React Navigation based on the data fetched from API?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-navigation-stack

Let's say there is a tab view which has tabs with names Breads, Pizzas, Beverages, Desserts, Shakes. And the name of these tabs are fetched from API. 
Also, the information for each tab to show on their respective screens is fetched from the API too.
Now, when one of the Tab's data gets deleted from the API. I want it to be removed from the Tab View too.

How can I achieve this in React Navigation?

Answer (score 1):

In react navigation we cannot have dynamic tab, as we have to define all the routes statically well in advance.

We had such requirement too, so we followed the below mentioned approach.

1. Define all the possible tabs statically and make tabs invisible.

> ```
> const MainNav = createBottomTabNavigator(
>   {
>     Breads: { screen: BreadsStackNavigation },
>     Pizzas: { screen: PizzasStackNavigation },
>     Beverages: { screen: BeveragesStackNavigation },
>     Desserts: { screen: DessertsStackNavigation },
>     Shakes: { screen: ShakesStackNavigation }
>   },
>   {
>     initialRouteName: 'HomeStackNavigation',
>     defaultNavigationOptions: {
>       tabBarVisible: false,
>     },
>     swipeEnabled: false,
>     navigationOptions: {
>       header: props => <HeaderView
>         navigation={props.navigation}
>       />,
>       tabBarVisible: false
>     }
>   }
> );
> ```

2. In the HeaderView, in `componentWillReceiveProps` check the response from the server and accordingly create tabs dynamically (may be by adding buttons dynamically depending on the responses).

**UPDATE**

I am thinking about one more approach.

As given in this [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html) we can create our own custom navigator, and populate the tabs dynamic in the parent custom navigator after getting response from the API call. I do not have the exact code for the same, but you can try this approach.

Comment: Gokul thank your answer! :) I did thought of this solution but it in this we're considering possible tabs, hence I think it's not really a feasible solution.

Comment: U can not achieve this with react navigation, you will have to change to react native navigation..

Comment: Is it possible using react native navigation?

Comment: yes, I dont know exactly how, but its possible, because in that we dont specify routes statically..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that maps the server response to RouteConfigs and call the function in the render method.

**WARNING**. using this approach is very risky because, on every re-render, the navigator is regenerated. If you can tweak your View no to re-render after creating the tabs, then you can get away with this approach.

```
 const mapArrayToTabs = (myArray) =>{
        let result = {}
        myArray.map( (item,index) =>{
            result[item] = {
                screen: ()=> <YourComponent/>,
                navigationOptions: {...}
            }
        } )
        return result
    }

    const createCustomTabs =()=>{

        const MyTabs = createAppContainer(
            createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
                mapArrayToTabs(["Screen1", "Screen2"] ),
                tabBarOptions: {...}
            )
        )

        return <MyTabs/>

    }


    render(){
        <View>
            {this.createCustomTabs()}
        </View>
    }
```